# Invisible labels and combo boxes affecting report lengths in Access

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2013

I have a report in Access that is from a checklist form for closing down projects. When the report is loaded, depending on the project type, certain labels and their combo boxes are marked as not visible. This is done using VBA and the visible property of each control. I have noticed that the report still includes these combo boxes and labels as blank white space. Is there a way to remove the white space?

I have set the detail and the overall report to can grow and can shrink. I am thinking about possibly using sub-reports to do this but I am unsure if it will work.

Edit: Another solution I am thinking about is building several different reports and using an if statement for the project type to determine which report to open but this feels excessive to me. This solution would report in at least 5 separate reports.

Answer (score 0):

Controls don't *take space* in Microsoft Access. They are positioned at a certain, predefined position, on a report of predefined size. There are little dynamic things about it (yes, nicomp is right, the CanGrow property makes it a tiny bit dynamic).

If you really want, you *can* move up all controls below a control you're hiding by the height of the control you're hiding, assuming controls take up the full width of the page. To do that, you can use something like the snippet below (iterate through all other controls):

```vb
If MyHiddenControl.Top < MyOtherControl.Top Then
    MyOtherControl.Move MyOtherControl.Left, MyOtherControl.Top - MyHiddenControl.Height
End If
```

And if you want to do it properly, add margins for controls and resize the report detail section too.

If controls don't take up the full width, it's considerably more difficult to dynamically organize your report.

Comment: What about the "can grow" property of a control? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/access-vba/articles/textbox-cangrow-property-access

Comment: @nicomp adjusted my answer accordingly